# Issue with create function inside Loopback framework

Tags: node.js, crud, loopback, v4l2loopback

I have this model

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

@model()
export class Coupon extends Entity {
  @property({
    id: true,
    type: 'string',
    required: false,
    mongo: {
      columnName: '_id',
      dataType: 'ObjectID',
    },
  })
  id: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  maximumUses: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  type: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  amount: number;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  maximumUsesPerPerson: number;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  validFrom: string;

  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  validTo: string;

  @property({
    type: 'number',
    required: true,
  })
  currentTotalUses: number;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
  })
  certainDays?: string[];

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
  })
  certainHours?: string[];

  @property({
    type: 'boolean',
    required: true,
  })
  valid: boolean;

  @property({
    type: 'array',
    itemType: 'string',
  })
  clients?: string[];

  @property({
    type: 'disabled',
    required: true,
  })
  disabled: boolean;

  constructor(data?: Partial<Coupon>) {
    super(data);
  }
}
```

repository for the model

```
import {DefaultCrudRepository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {Coupon} from '../models';
import {TestDataSource} from '../datasources';
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';

export class CouponRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  Coupon,
  typeof Coupon.prototype.id
> {
  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.test') dataSource: TestDataSource,
  ) {
    super(Coupon, dataSource);
  }
}
```

now the following function should works well

```
await this.couponsRepo.create({ name: 'string',
    maximumUses: 0,
    maximumUsesPerPerson: 0,
    amount: 0,
    validFrom: 'string',
    validTo: 'string',
    type: 'percentage',
    valid: true,
    currentTotalUses: 0,
    disabled: false });
```

but it fires this error

> ReferenceError: g is not defined
>       at new disabled (eval at createModelClassCtor (../LBIssue/lbissue/node_modules/loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js:678:21), :10:27)

to simply produce this error , create empty loopback 4 project
then put the coupon model = with the code I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your model definition.

See this

```
@property({
    type: 'disabled',
    required: true,
  })
  disabled: boolean;
```

type cannot be disabled. It should be

```
@property({
        type: 'boolean',
        required: true,
      })
      disabled: boolean;
```